# Unit test best practice in Spring boot for mocking on service level

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

We have a unit test, where we are testing the redeeming of a promotion code. 
We need to check if two parameters exist in the database:  `Entity` & `User`

In the code you will see,

1. we create instances of `User` and `Entity`
2. Insert into the db (with a @Repository)
3. Create a DTO ..etc too

Because the `RedeemService` will call the `User` and `Entity` services to check that these exist.

I have the feeling that instead of doing all this, we should be able to mock (the User & Entity Services)

Here is the test:

```
@Test 
    public void redeemPromoCodeTestValid() throws Exception {

        String userId = "OOUser";
        String fleetId = "F0001";
        String promoCodeId = "AFTER_CHRIS";

        User user = new User();
        user.setId(userId);
        user.setFleetId(fleetId);
        user.setUserName("OOabcdefg");
        userRepository.save(user);

        EntityX entity = new EntityX(); //EntityX, because Entity is a reserved keyword..
        entityRepository.save(entity);
        String entityId = entityRepository.findAll().get(0).getId();

        PromoCode promoCode = createPromoCode(promoCodeId);
        promoCodeRepository.save(promoCode);

        RedeemDTO add = new RedeemDTO();
        add.setUserId(userId);
        add.setEntityId(entityId);
        String jsonString = this.asJsonString(add);
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/billing/fleets/"+ fleetId + "/promoCodes/redeem/" + promoCodeId).content(jsonString).contentType(CONTENT_TYPE);

        mockMvcPromocode.perform(requestBuilder).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());

        List<Wallet> find = walletService.findWalletByEntityId(entityId);
        assertThat(find.size()).isEqualTo(1);
    }
```

I am new to Spring boot and unit test mocking, so any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of different definitions of the words, there are tests testing just your code of just one class (unit tests), tests testing the Spring integration and http handling (integration tests), and tests testing your whole application end-to-end (end-to-end tests). It is not clear which kind of test you want to write.

If you want to write a unit test, you need to decide which is the unit you want to test. If you want to test the controller, just test the Java class without using MockHttpServletRequestBuilder and SpringRunner.

Any Spring Class is also a normal Java class, you can unit test them the same way you test any other class. However it becomes easiest if you use constructor injection:

```
@Service
class FooService {

    private final FooBean foo;

    @Autowired
    public FooService(FooBean foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}

public class FooServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void testFooService() {
        fooMock = mock(FooBean.class); // use Mockito or EasyMock, or real FooBean
        FooService fooService = new FooService(fooMock);
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want to write an integration tests for your controllers, use MockHttpServletRequestBuilder and mock your service layer.

To do that, use something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ControllerTestConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerTest {
    ...
}

@Configuration
public class ControllerTestConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserService userServiceMock() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And for end-to-end tests, use no mocks, but possibly a separate Spring profile to connect to test backend resources / in-memory databases.

Comment: Thus the question: can service class be tested with only unit test? And how to write that?

Comment: I added an example